# WAS 6.1 shows Java version 5, but its really 1.4

Tags: java, jsp, websphere, websphere-6.1

I have a strange problem.

I have configured our Websphere Application Server to run Java 5. Its a really old application that I have migrated from Java 4.

If I in the jsp page print

```
System.getProperty("java.version")
System.getProperty("java.specification.version")
System.getProperty("java.vm.name")
```

I get

**Java version: 1.5.0

java.specification.version: 1.5

java.vm.name:   IBM J9 VM**

However, If I in the jsp change the code from `List` to `List<Object>` I get the following exception:

`The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Object>
JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 79 in the file: /jsp/archive/archiveoverview.jsp
JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /jsp/archive/archiveoverview.jsp 
C:\SDP75\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\temp\CR122599Node01\server1\myifEAR\myif.war\jsp\archive\_archiveoverview.java : 199 : Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0`

How can this be???

Comment: this may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036544/why-websphere-6-1-jdk-1-5-compliant-compiles-my-jsps-as-jdk-1-4.

Comment: Websphere 6.1 is a J2EE 1.4 Container, but running on a JDK 1.5...

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I suggest just to close this thread then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JVM used to run WebSphere Application Server is different from the compiler compliance level used to compile JSPs running within the server.  See this technote: [Using Java 5 language feature in a JSP targeting WebSphere Application Server v6.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264609).

Comment: Although, I think this is a duplicate, I will accept since this is exactly what I did.